# Date Diff Human Format Output in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, unix-timestamp

Ok I have found so many threads on this topic, but can't find one that seems to be working for me.

I've got a script that is working, but only if the input date is today, but I have a date for example that's `Sunday 7th of July at 10:51am`, and it's coming up as `Thursday at 12:33 pm`, and anything older than a week is coming up as `January 1 at 12:33 pm`.

This is my script so far (The input date `$timestamp` is in the format `Y-m-d H:i:s`)

```
function dateDiff($timestamp) {
if(empty($timestamp)) {
    return "No date provided";
}
// Get time difference and setup arrays
$unix_date = strtotime($timestamp);
if(empty($unix_date)) {    
    return "Bad date";
}
$difference = time() - $unix_date;
$periods = array("second", "minute", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "years");
$lengths = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12"); 
// Past or present
if ($difference >= 0) {
    $ending = "ago";
} else {
    $difference = -$difference;
    $ending = "to go";
} 
// Figure out difference by looping while less than array length
// and difference is larger than lengths.
$arr_len = count($lengths);
for($j = 0; $j < $arr_len && $difference >= $lengths[$j]; $j++) {
    $difference /= $lengths[$j];
} 
// Round up     
$difference = round($difference); 
// Make plural if needed
if($difference != 1) {
    $periods[$j].= "s";
} 
// Default format
$text = $difference." ".$periods[$j]." ".$ending; 
// over 24 hours
if($j > 2) {
    // future date over a day formate with year
    if($ending == "to go") {
        if($j == 3 && $difference == 1) {
            $text = "Tomorrow at ". date("g:i a", $timestamp);
        } else {
            $text = date("F j, Y \a\\t g:i a", $timestamp);
        }
        return $text;
    } 
    if($j == 3 && $difference == 1) { // Yesterday
        $text = "Yesterday at ". date("g:i a", $timestamp);
    } else if($j == 3) { // Less than a week display -- Monday at 5:28pm
        $text = date("l \a\\t g:i a", $timestamp);
    } else if($j < 6 && !($j == 5 && $difference == 12)) { // Less than a year display -- June 25 at 5:23am
        $text = date("F j \a\\t g:i a", $timestamp);
    } else { // if over a year or the same month one year ago -- June 30, 2010 at 5:34pm
        $text = date("F j, Y \a\\t g:i a", $timestamp);
    }
} 
return $text;
}
```

Can anyone see what may be making it show the wrong information??

Comment: Is this of any use? https://github.com/vascowhite/TimeAgo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. I added the following. My error reports took a bit to come through so I didn't see them at first

```
if(empty($timestamp)) {
    return "No date provided";
} else {
    $timestamp = strtotime($timestamp);
}
```